# Android: alternate background color in a TableLayout inside a ListView

Tags: android, listview, background-color, tablelayout, alternate

I'm trying to display a set of data in a Grid style, using a TableLayout inside a ListView. What I want is to display each row with a different color (two colors alternatively). It works well when using a normal LinearLayout in the ListView, but for whatever reason when using a TableLayout I end up having all rows having the same background, which I think is the last one set.

For this, I am using a BaseAdapter, and in the getView function I have something like:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.from = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.from);
                holder.to = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.to);

                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
            if(position%2==0) {
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.cell_background);
            }
            //alternate background
            else {
                convertView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.cell_background_alternate);
            }

            // Bind the data efficiently with the holder.
            holder.from.setText(list.get(position)[0]);
            holder.to.setText(list.get(position)[1]);

            return convertView;
        }
```

Now in my main.xml for the activity, I just have a ListView. In the list.xml used to inflate the list, I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/from"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <TextView android:id="@+id/to"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Also, another problem is that the columns are not aligned: it just takes as much space as it needs for every row, every columns, when a TableLayout should align all columns. The only workaround that I came up with was to set a minimal width for the columns, but that's not pretty. Any reason why it does not work here?

Edit 21/06:
[image: cell not aligned]

As you can see on the picture, the columns are not aligned (row 2 and 3 are but it's obviously because they have the same data inside).

Answer (score 0):

try replacing

convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent, false);

with

convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);

and for table cell aligning issue can you give an example snapshot bcos I did not get what u trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your way, but it didn't change anything. I added a screenshot of what it looks like: every row should have a different background and for example 4 should come under Results

Comment: for table alignment try android:gravity="left" instead of android:layout_gravity="left". And for coloring I don't know why its not working, can you try changing color of main table layout instead of complete view.

Comment: android:gravity="left" does not change anything. What do you mean by changing the main table color? what I want is to have each row a different color, changing the color of the whole table won't help me much...

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced same problem of alignment of table header and table row having data but after lot of efforts i found the only way to get rid of this problem is to give fix size to all the columns